# How to execute mysql queries using salt state

Tags: mysql, salt-stack

I want to execute a mysql query. I want to change the root password for mysql. How can I do this using salt state? My SLS file looks like this

```
test:
 mysql_query.run:
    - order: 2
    - database: '*'
    - query: |
       - "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
       - "SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('root');"
       - "UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('root') WHERE User='root';"
```

I think the state mysql_query.run executes only database related query so it expects database. So when I run above sls I get 'database test not found message' and it doesn't change the password of root to root. How can I solve this ?

Comment: Please I need an answer

Answer (score 0):

The database where MySQL stores passwords is called `mysql`. The following state updated the root password for me. Please note that I also updated the multiline syntax.

```
test:
  mysql_query.run:
    - database: mysql
    - query: |
       FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
       SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('root');
       UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('root') WHERE User='root';
```